# How to execute bash with ssh connection

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I'm trying to write a bash script to automatically do stuff in clients machines in the network. But after the code

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key root@machine
```

The bash program just stops 
What can I do to send the command to the remote machine?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it 'just stops'?

Comment: It means the bash stops and the screens shows the connexion with the client's machine, waiting for my command. The programs continues when I type "exit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way as if you were invoking bash directly.

```
ssh ... somescriptontheserver.sh

ssh ... ls -lR /

ssh ... << EOF
ls -lR /
EOF
```